# add and remove subview in code block doesn't animate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I have this code for flashing an image on a map as a part of MKAnnotationView:

```
    UIView* containerView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:enemy];
    UIImageView* redCircle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red_half_circle.png"]];


    [UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                      duration:2.9
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse&&UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                    animations:^{ [containerView addSubview:redCircle];}
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){[redCircle removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

As such, nothing happens when I run it.  But!!! If I remove the "completion" code block and replace it with NULL, then at least the animation adds the subview.  Maybe the options have something to do with it?

Question: How do you flash an image in MKAnnotationView?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

First things first:

You've specified `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse&&UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`. This is a "logical AND", not a "bitwise AND". `Autoreverse` is 16 (`1<<4`) and `Repeat` is 8 (`1<<3`), so `Autoreverse&&Repeat` is `16&&8` which is the same as `1` (since they're evaluated as truth values), which happens to be the same as `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews`.

You want `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse&UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`.

Second: You haven't specified a transition; this is equivalent to specifying `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone`. I *think* this means that the duration is ignored (because you've specified `...TransitionNone`), so completion happens immediately, so you don't see a thing.

Third: I also don't think that `UIView` transitions can be repeated/reversed (it would need to keep track of the views you've removed/added; as far as I know it only keeps a "screenshot" of the initial state), but I could be wrong.

You may have better luck with something like this:

```
[containerView addSubview:redCircle];
redCircle.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.9
  delay:0
  options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse&UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
  animation:^{redCircle.alpha = 1;}
  completion:NULL];
```

This should make it fade in and out. You *might* be able to make it flash by setting `redCircle.hidden` instead (`UIView.hidden` is not documented as animatable, but `CALayer.hidden` is animatable, so it might still work).

Comment: Though anecdotal, it's definitely my experience that the hidden property is animatable.

Comment: Does it change hidden-ness half-way through the animation?